# Elbow grinding sensation after starting workout

Tags: weightlifting

First up, I know there are any elbow noise questions out there, but they do not describe my experience completely.

Okay so I'm 18 yrs old and very skinny with little muscle, and I started gym a month ago.

So 2-3 weeks ago, I started getting this creaky grinding sensation when I completely extend my arm or completely bend it, you can't hear it out loud, just feel it by putting your fingers on the elbow, this sound is different from the knuckle pop or knee crack etc, its much more gentler.

I do not feel any kind of pain or secondary symptoms like swelling or locked range of motion.

When I told my trainer about it, he said its completely normal and happens because the muscle around my elbows are weak(indeed).

The sound when extending comes from a little right of the inner side of the elbow(not ulnar nerve) but when bending its kinda like from the middle of the inner elbow.

Ps.- Ever since I joined, I've been told to do wrist curls with a barbell, earlier barbell alone, then 2.5KG plates each side and currently 5kg each side. I do 100 reps of this with little rest in between.

So could it be due to this exercise? my left arm is non dominant and thus relatively weaker.

So should I stop doing these wrist exercises or just keep doing the and fortify my elbow muscles? since there is no pain or discomfort in the elbow itself while doing it.

Comment: Checkout this Q/A, one guy put a good answer that may help answer yours: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/kettlebell-hurting-my-wrist

Answer (score 4):

Elbow grinding or not, you should stop the 100 rep sessions immediately.

[Read Dave's answer over here.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24757/number-of-reps-for-lean-muscles)

Long story short, you're not building muscle at all by doing 100 reps. Instead, add more weight, and do 3-4 sets of 8-12 reps. There should be enough weight to make you regret the last couple reps. In other words, you should just barely be able to do it.

As for the elbow pain, we mostly give the same advice. We don't know. We *can't* know. You should get an examination by a doctor. But yes, it could very likely be due to the 100 reps. Such a workout would do more harm for your joints, than it does good for your muscles.

Comment: Well thanks but as I said there is no pain during movement of the elbow.
It just feels like a "tuck" in and "tuck" out noise when extending and bending the elbow. And as for the excercise, it is the only excercice I struggle too much with, myabe I should stop doing it for few weeks and see if this noise has improved.

Answer (score 2):

I would stop when I hear or feel grinding noise, or use lighter weights if that gets rid of the feeling. My reason would be because of a similar no pain grinding feeling from my neck would follow with 2-3 weeks of swelling and pain that build up slowly over a couple of days then goes away slowly over a few weeks. I run during this time but only because I dont hear or feel any grinding noise or pain. In your case there seems to be no swelling or pain associated with it, but I would work around the grinding instead of pushing through it.

Comment: Well the only time I can physically feel it now is when I extend y arms during lat-pull downs, other times I have to put two fingers on the area and move the arm to feel it. But one thing I noticed, after stopping the wrist exercise for 2 days, this grind feels much softer and compact, idk if it is healing or not...

Comment: @Invoker Im not any expert but Id say it was healing during those days, but I bet taking it easier for a period of time while still working out would get you the same result.

Answer (score -3):

Oh dear! 100 Reps. No invoker. As @Alec said, you should seriously stop during 100 reps. Use heavier weights and do lower reps.

You will majorly damage yourself with 100 reps. As for the elbow pain, I am not qualified to comment.